# How to add custom icons to react-image-gallery

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react-image-gallery.
https://github.com/xiaolin/react-image-gallery

I would like to substitute the default icons for full-screen, left arrow, right arrow for my own designs. I can see they are inline SVG elements. I think I would have to render custom controls or something but don't know how to do it.

```
<div className="image-gallery-wrapper">
    <ImageGallery 
      items={images} 
      autoPlay={false}
      showThumbnails={true}
      useBrowserFullscreen={false}
      showPlayButton={false}
      showBullets={true}
      showIndex={true}
       />
  </div>
```

Update:
I managed to get close with:

```
const FullScreenButton = ({ onClick, isFullScreen }) => {
   return isFullScreen ?
      <button type="button" className="image-gallery-icon image-gallery-fullscreen-button" onClick={onClick} aria-label="Open Fullscreen">Open</button>
:
      <button type="button" className="image-gallery-icon image-gallery-fullscreen-button Closed" onClick={onClick} aria-label="Close Fullscreen">Closed</button>
}
```

and

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="image-gallery-wrapper">
        <ImageGallery 
          items={images} 
          autoPlay={false}
          showThumbnails={true}
          useBrowserFullscreen={false}
          showPlayButton={false}
          showBullets={true}
          showIndex={true}
          renderFullscreenButton={(onClick, isFullscreen) => (
            <FullScreenButton onClick={onClick} isFullscreen=  {isFullscreen} />
          )}
         />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I can place an SVG image where the open and close text is. But when it opens and closes it always stays at closed. Can someone see if there is something wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the npm page of the package, you can use props like `renderLeftNav`, `renderRightNav`, and `renderFullscreenButton` to accomplish this.
first, if you have your SVG icons, we can make them into components:

```
function LeftArrowButton({ onClick }){
  //handle function for when this button is clicked in here
  return (
    <svg> ... </svg>
)}

function RightArrowButton({ onClick }){
  //handle function for when this button is clicked in here
  return (
    <svg> ... </svg>
)}

function FullScreenButton({ onClick, isFullscreen }){
  //handle function for when this button is clicked in here, or when full screen is activated
  return (
    <svg> ... </svg>
)}
```

Then you can di this in your `ImageGallery` component

```
<div className="image-gallery-wrapper">
    <ImageGallery 
      items={images} 
      autoPlay={false}
      showThumbnails={true}
      useBrowserFullscreen={false}
      showPlayButton={false}
      showBullets={true}
      showIndex={true}
      //
      renderLeftNav= {(onClick, _disabled) => (
        <LeftArrowButton onClick={onClick} />
      )}
      renderRightNav= {(onClick, _disabled) => (
        <RightArrowButton onClick={onClick} />
      )}
      renderFullscreenButton= {(onClick, isFullscreen) => (
        <FullScreenButton onClick={onClick} isFullscreen={isFullscreen} />
      )},
       />
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. You got me almost there. I can replace the SVG with my own. Wrapped with the <button> tag and classes. But now the button doesn't work. I'm very new to React, do I have to register the new button someplace in the app?

Comment: You'll have to add `onClick` event handlers for the buttons to work. They are just functions that fire whenever that button is clicked.